# In asp.net ,How can split below cartype values"honda,tata" in the form of 'honda' and ' tata' in two different lines?

Tags: arrays, asp.net, database, split

```
Public bool cardetailsinsert(string name,string cartype)
String[] cartype= cartype.split()
```

Comment: Do you mean like....`cartype.Split(',')`

Comment: What means in two different lines? You want a ner string where all items which were originally separated by `,` are now separated by `NewLine`? Or you mean that you want both information as separate variables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.